# Get a Discord Role by Id. Discrod.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I get a Role object by the role's id using "discord.Guild.get_role()"?

I use it like this
`role = discord.Guild.get_role(role_id=config.ROLE_ID)`

but I have a error after:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Master\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Master\Desktop\ДЗ\Python\DiscrodBot\bot.py", line 15, in on_member_join
    role = discord.Guild.get_role(role_id=config.ROLE_ID)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Guild.get_role() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'role_id'
```

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import config

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.BOT_CMD_PREFIX, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if config.IS_ADD_ROLE_CONNECTION_MEMBER:
        role = discord.Guild.get_role(role_id=config.ROLE_ID)
        await member.add_roles(role)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting means that [Guild.get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) does not take any keyword arguments like `role_id=`.

[discord.Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild) is the raw class object from `discord`. You can get the `Guild` object from the guild attribute from [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member).

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if config.IS_ADD_ROLE_CONNECTION_MEMBER:
        guild = member.guild 
        role = guild.get_role(id_here)
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

- The code takes the [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.guild) attribute from [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) and stores it into `guild`.
- Uses the [get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) method with the positional argument `id_here` and stores it into `role` for use.

Relevant documentation: [Guild.get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role), [discord.Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild), [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member)